# how install bluez 5.19 in raspberry

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, raspbian, bluez

i try compile and install bluez 5.19 in raspberry via these command :

./configure

result :

```
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking how to create a pax tar archive... gnutar
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for C/C++ restrict keyword... __restrict
checking for gcc... (cached) gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking dependency style of gcc... (cached) gcc3
checking whether gcc and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -fPIE... yes
checking build system type... armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking host system type... armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert armv6l-unknown-linux-gnueabihf file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... mt
checking if mt is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc linker (/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
checking for signalfd... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking for dlopen in -ldl... yes
checking for GLIB... yes
checking for DBUS... yes
checking D-Bus configuration directory... /usr/local/etc
checking D-Bus system bus services dir... /usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services
checking D-Bus session bus services dir... /usr/local/share/dbus-1/services
checking for UDEV... yes
checking for udev_hwdb_new in -ludev... no
checking udev directory... /lib/udev
checking for ICAL... yes
checking readline/readline.h usability... yes
checking readline/readline.h presence... yes
checking for readline/readline.h... yes
checking systemd system unit dir... /lib/systemd/system
checking systemd user unit dir... /usr/lib/systemd/user
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating src/bluetoothd.8
config.status: creating lib/bluez.pc
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: config.h is unchanged
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands
```

sudo make

Result :

```
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/bluetooth.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/hci.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/hci_lib.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/sco.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/l2cap.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/sdp.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/sdp_lib.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/rfcomm.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/bnep.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/cmtp.h
  GEN    lib/bluetooth/hidp.h
  GEN    src/builtin.h
  GEN    obexd/src/builtin.h
make --no-print-directory all-am
  CC     lib/bluetooth.lo
  CC     lib/hci.lo
  CC     lib/sdp.lo
  CC     lib/uuid.lo
  CCLD   lib/libbluetooth-internal.la
  CC     gdbus/mainloop.lo
  CC     gdbus/watch.lo
  CC     gdbus/object.lo
  CC     gdbus/client.lo
  CC     gdbus/polkit.lo
  CCLD   gdbus/libgdbus-internal.la
  CC     client/main.o
  CC     client/display.o
  CC     client/agent.o
  CC     monitor/uuid.o
  CCLD   client/bluetoothctl
  CC     monitor/main.o
  CC     monitor/mainloop.o
  CC     monitor/display.o
  CC     monitor/hcidump.o
  CC     monitor/ellisys.o
  CC     monitor/control.o
  CC     monitor/packet.o
  CC     monitor/vendor.o
  CC     monitor/lmp.o
  CC     monitor/crc.o
  CC     monitor/ll.o
  CC     monitor/l2cap.o
  CC     monitor/sdp.o
  CC     monitor/hwdb.o
  CC     monitor/keys.o
  CC     monitor/analyze.o
  CC     src/shared/util.o
  CC     src/shared/queue.o
  CC     src/shared/crypto.o
  CC     src/shared/btsnoop.o
  CCLD   monitor/btmon
  CC     tools/hciattach.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_st.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_ti.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_tialt.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_ath3k.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_qualcomm.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_intel.o
  CC     tools/hciattach_bcm43xx.o
  CCLD   tools/hciattach
  CC     tools/hciconfig.o
  CC     tools/csr.o
  CCLD   tools/hciconfig
  CC     tools/hcitool.o
  CC     src/oui.o
  CCLD   tools/hcitool
  CC     tools/hcidump.o
  CC     tools/parser/parser.o
  CC     tools/parser/lmp.o
  CC     tools/parser/hci.o
  CC     tools/parser/l2cap.o
  CC     tools/parser/amp.o
  CC     tools/parser/smp.o
  CC     tools/parser/att.o
  CC     tools/parser/sdp.o
  CC     tools/parser/rfcomm.o
  CC     tools/parser/bnep.o
  CC     tools/parser/cmtp.o
  CC     tools/parser/hidp.o
  CC     tools/parser/hcrp.o
  CC     tools/parser/avdtp.o
  CC     tools/parser/avctp.o
  CC     tools/parser/avrcp.o
  CC     tools/parser/sap.o
  CC     tools/parser/obex.o
  CC     tools/parser/capi.o
  CC     tools/parser/ppp.o
  CC     tools/parser/tcpip.o
  CC     tools/parser/ericsson.o
  CC     tools/parser/csr.o
  CC     tools/parser/bpa.o
  CCLD   tools/hcidump
  CC     tools/rfcomm.o
  CCLD   tools/rfcomm
  CC     tools/rctest.o
  CCLD   tools/rctest
  CC     tools/l2test.o
  CCLD   tools/l2test
  CC     tools/l2ping.o
  CCLD   tools/l2ping
  CC     tools/sdptool.o
  CC     src/sdp-xml.o
  CCLD   tools/sdptool
  CC     tools/ciptool.o
  CCLD   tools/ciptool
  CC     tools/bccmd.o
  CC     tools/csr_hci.o
  CC     tools/csr_usb.o
  CC     tools/csr_h4.o
  CC     tools/csr_3wire.o
  CC     tools/csr_bcsp.o
  CC     tools/ubcsp.o
  CCLD   tools/bccmd
  CC     tools/bluemoon.o
  CC     src/shared/io-mainloop.o
  CC     src/shared/hci.o
  CC     src/shared/ringbuf.o
  CCLD   tools/bluemoon
  CC     profiles/cups/main.o
  CC     profiles/cups/sdp.o
  CC     profiles/cups/spp.o
  CC     profiles/cups/hcrp.o
  CCLD   profiles/cups/bluetooth
  CC     plugins/bluetoothd-hostname.o
  CC     plugins/bluetoothd-wiimote.o
  CC     plugins/bluetoothd-autopair.o
  CC     plugins/bluetoothd-policy.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-source.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-sink.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-a2dp.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-avdtp.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-media.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-transport.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-control.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-avctp.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-avrcp.o
  CC     profiles/audio/bluetoothd-player.o
  CC     profiles/network/bluetoothd-manager.o
  CC     profiles/network/bluetoothd-bnep.o
  CC     profiles/network/bluetoothd-server.o
  CC     profiles/network/bluetoothd-connection.o
  CC     profiles/input/bluetoothd-manager.o
  CC     profiles/input/bluetoothd-server.o
  CC     profiles/input/bluetoothd-device.o
  CC     profiles/input/bluetoothd-hog.o
  CC     profiles/input/bluetoothd-suspend-dummy.o
  CC     profiles/gatt/bluetoothd-gas.o
  CC     profiles/scanparam/bluetoothd-scan.o
  CC     profiles/deviceinfo/bluetoothd-deviceinfo.o
  CC     attrib/bluetoothd-att.o
  CC     attrib/bluetoothd-gatt.o
  CC     attrib/bluetoothd-gattrib.o
  CC     attrib/bluetoothd-gatt-service.o
  CC     btio/bluetoothd-btio.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-main.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-log.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-systemd.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-rfkill.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdpd-server.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdpd-request.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdpd-service.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdpd-database.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-attrib-server.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdp-xml.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-sdp-client.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-textfile.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-uuid-helper.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-plugin.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-storage.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-agent.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-error.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-adapter.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-profile.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-service.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-gatt-dbus.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-gatt.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-device.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-dbus-common.o
  CC     src/bluetoothd-eir.o
  CC     src/shared/bluetoothd-io-glib.o
  CC     src/shared/bluetoothd-timeout-glib.o
  CC     src/shared/bluetoothd-queue.o
  CC     src/shared/bluetoothd-util.o
  CC     src/shared/bluetoothd-mgmt.o
  GEN    src/bluetooth.service
  CCLD   src/bluetoothd
  CC     btio/obexd-btio.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex-defs.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex-packet.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex-header.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex-transfer.o
  CC     gobex/obexd-gobex-apparam.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-filesystem.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-bluetooth.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-opp.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-ftp.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-irmc.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-pbap.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-vcard.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-phonebook-dummy.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-mas.o
  CC     obexd/plugins/obexd-messages-dummy.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-mns.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-main.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-plugin.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-log.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-manager.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-obex.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-mimetype.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-service.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-transport.o
  CC     obexd/src/obexd-server.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-manager.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-session.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-bluetooth.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-sync.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-pbap.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-ftp.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-opp.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-map.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-map-event.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-transfer.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-transport.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-dbus.o
  CC     obexd/client/obexd-driver.o
  CCLD   obexd/src/obexd
  CC     attrib/gatttool.o
  CC     attrib/att.o
  CC     attrib/gatt.o
  CC     attrib/gattrib.o
  CC     btio/btio.o
  CC     attrib/interactive.o
  CC     attrib/utils.o
  CC     src/log.o
  CCLD   attrib/gatttool
  CC     gobex/gobex.o
  CC     gobex/gobex-defs.o
  CC     gobex/gobex-packet.o
  CC     gobex/gobex-header.o
  CC     gobex/gobex-transfer.o
  CC     gobex/gobex-apparam.o
  CC     tools/obex-client-tool.o
  CCLD   tools/obex-client-tool
  CC     tools/obex-server-tool.o
  CCLD   tools/obex-server-tool
  CC     tools/bluetooth-player.o
  CCLD   tools/bluetooth-player
  CC     tools/obexctl.o
  CCLD   tools/obexctl
  CC     unit/test-eir.o
  CC     src/eir.o
  CC     src/uuid-helper.o
  CCLD   unit/test-eir
  CC     unit/test-uuid.o
  CCLD   unit/test-uuid
  CC     unit/test-textfile.o
  CC     src/textfile.o
  CCLD   unit/test-textfile
  CC     unit/test-crc.o
  CCLD   unit/test-crc
  CC     unit/test-ringbuf.o
  CCLD   unit/test-ringbuf
  CC     unit/test-queue.o
  CCLD   unit/test-queue
  CC     unit/test-mgmt.o
  CC     src/shared/io-glib.o
  CC     src/shared/mgmt.o
  CCLD   unit/test-mgmt
  CC     unit/test-sdp.o
  CC     src/sdpd-database.o
  CC     src/sdpd-service.o
  CC     src/sdpd-request.o
  CCLD   unit/test-sdp
  CC     unit/test-avdtp.o
  CC     android/avdtp.o
  CCLD   unit/test-avdtp
  CC     unit/test-avctp.o
  CC     android/avctp.o
  CCLD   unit/test-avctp
  CC     unit/test-avrcp.o
  CC     android/avrcp-lib.o
  CCLD   unit/test-avrcp
  CC     unit/test-hfp.o
  CC     src/shared/hfp.o
  CCLD   unit/test-hfp
  CC     unit/test-gdbus-client.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gdbus-client
  CC     unit/util.o
  CC     unit/test-gobex-header.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gobex-header
  CC     unit/test-gobex-packet.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gobex-packet
  CC     unit/test-gobex.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gobex
  CC     unit/test-gobex-transfer.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gobex-transfer
  CC     unit/test-gobex-apparam.o
  CCLD   unit/test-gobex-apparam
  CC     unit/test-lib.o
  CCLD   unit/test-lib
  CC     tools/hid2hci.o
  CCLD   tools/hid2hci
  GEN    tools/97-hid2hci.rules
  GEN    obexd/src/obex.service
```

and finally make install

Result :

```
make --no-print-directory install-am
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/bin'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c client/bluetoothctl monitor/btmon tools/hciattach tools/hciconfig tools/hcitool tools/hcidump tools/rfcomm tools/rctest tools/l2test tools/l2ping tools/sdptool tools/ciptool tools/bccmd tools/bluemoon '/usr/local/bin'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c client/bluetoothctl /usr/local/bin/bluetoothctl
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c monitor/btmon /usr/local/bin/btmon
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hciattach /usr/local/bin/hciattach
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hciconfig /usr/local/bin/hciconfig
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hcitool /usr/local/bin/hcitool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hcidump /usr/local/bin/hcidump
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/rfcomm /usr/local/bin/rfcomm
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/rctest /usr/local/bin/rctest
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/l2test /usr/local/bin/l2test
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/l2ping /usr/local/bin/l2ping
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/sdptool /usr/local/bin/sdptool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/ciptool /usr/local/bin/ciptool
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/bccmd /usr/local/bin/bccmd
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/bluemoon /usr/local/bin/bluemoon
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c src/bluetoothd obexd/src/obexd '/usr/local/libexec/bluetooth'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c src/bluetoothd /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c obexd/src/obexd /usr/local/libexec/bluetooth/obexd
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib/cups/backend'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c profiles/cups/bluetooth '/usr/local/lib/cups/backend'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c profiles/cups/bluetooth /usr/local/lib/cups/backend/bluetooth
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/etc/dbus-1/system.d'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetooth.conf '/usr/local/etc/dbus-1/system.d'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/dbus-1/services'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 obexd/src/org.bluez.obex.service '/usr/local/share/dbus-1/services'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/org.bluez.service '/usr/local/share/dbus-1/system-services'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tools/hciattach.1 tools/hciconfig.1 tools/hcitool.1 tools/hcidump.1 tools/rfcomm.1 tools/rctest.1 tools/l2ping.1 tools/sdptool.1 tools/ciptool.1 tools/bccmd.1 tools/hid2hci.1 '/usr/local/share/man/man1'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetoothd.8 '/usr/local/share/man/man8'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/udev/rules.d'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 tools/97-hid2hci.rules '/lib/udev/rules.d'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/systemd/system'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 src/bluetooth.service '/lib/systemd/system'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/systemd/user'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 obexd/src/obex.service '/usr/lib/systemd/user'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/lib/udev'
  /bin/bash ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c tools/hid2hci '/lib/udev'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c tools/hid2hci /lib/udev/hid2hci
```

but bluez command not define in terminal and in python bluetooth library wont work ...
what is my worng ?

please help

Comment: It looks like everything was installed successfully. Go to the same directory from which you ran ./configure, then type ./tools/hcitool scan. What is the output when you run that command?

Comment: bluetooth work fine but on old version 4.99 ...
when i execute command 'bluetoothd -v' still show 4.99 version

Comment: Yes but you are not operating from the same folder on which you installed bluez 5.19. Go to that folder and try ./tools/hcitool scan.

Comment: ./tools/hcitool scan find my device ...
out is :
Scanning ...
 6C:0E:0D:3A:1F:90 Walkman

Now what do I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so it seems that the installation was successful, but you still need to add the executables to one of the directories in the PATH environment variable for it to be directly executed from anywhere. First thing, to view the directories that are in the PATH variable, try the following command:

```
#echo $PATH
```

You should see something like this:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Now add the executables you want to use (e.g. hcitool, hciconfig, bluetoothd) to one of these directories, ideally to /usr/bin or /usr/sbin as this is where the original bluez executables are located. Example

```
cp tools/hcitool /usr/bin/
```

However, make sure that you **move the original bluez executables** (the files that are already in one of the directories of the PATH variable) somewhere else to avoid conflicts.

I hope this helps.